# Why php mail() function displays subject two times (localhost)

Tags: php, email, subject

I'm using `XAMPP` and when I send an email with PHP `mail()` function the subject comes two times (like "hello, hello").

**PHP Code:**

```
$from="me@gmail.com"; 
$to="you@gmail.com";
$subject="hello";
$message="this doesn't work nicely";
$headers = 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
        'Subject: '.$subject."\r\n".
         'Mime-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";

mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $headers);
```

**Does anyone know the solution?**

Comment: Just remove it from the `$headers`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the $headers are the issue here:

```
$from="me@gmail.com";

$to="you@gmail.com";

$subject="hello";

$message="this doesn't work nicely";

mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message,);
```

Comment: But why my original code works fine with other server but not with localhost? Should some editing be made in php.ini or sendmail.ini files?

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving when you try to send via localhost?

Comment: If you install an SMTP server and configure localhost to listen on port  25.  Some people recommend Postfix.

Comment: There comes no error message because the email is send but the subject is displayed two times for some reason.

Comment: Ok. so going back to your original question, you can now send email from localhost?

Comment: Var_dump($subject) to see what's actually getting passed